# pdo проверить зарегестрирован ли пользователь

Tags: php, pdo

Как через PDO проверить, зарегистрирован ли пользователь? Я пробовал:

```
include '../db.php'; 
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM users");
while ( $row = $stmt->fetchAll() ) {
    $login_in_data = $row['login'];
    $email_in_data = $row['email'];
}
echo count($row); // Возвращает 0 ==> он не достает нужные мне данные с бд
if ( $login_in_data == NULL ) {
    echo "Логин в бд: ";
    var_dump($login_in_data); //мне для проверки
    unset($login_in_data);
} elseif ( isset($login_in_data) ) {
    echo "Такой логин уже зарегестрирован!";
}
if ( $email_in_data == NULL ) {
    echo "Почта в бд: ";
    var_dump($email_in_data); // мне для проверки
    unset($email_in_data);
} if ( isset($email_in_data) ) {
    echo "Такая почта уже зарегестрирована!";
}
// ... Код регистрации...
```

Но на чём наткнулся - пометил комментарием. Как будет лучше сделать?

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/check_email_exists#check

Answer (score 0):

Я никогда не работал с pdo ранее, чуть по другому взаимодействовал с базой данных (могу скинуть свой пример, если дальнейший совет не поможет), но сейчас поискал информацию - 
http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php

fetchAll() возвращает массив строк, а потому

```
$login_in_data = $row['login']; // Не так
$login_in_data = $row[0]['login']; // А так хотя бы
```

Но почему `echo count($row);` возвращает 0 - пока думаю, ищу, не могу сам понять))

Comment: 1) потому что предлагаю показать альтернативное решение, если будет желание им воспользоваться.
2) потому что нашел одну ошибку и предлагаю исправление.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `login` FROM `users ` WHERE `login`= :login AND `password` = :password";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(
        'login' => $login,
        'password' => $pass
    ));
    $mass = $sth->fetch();
    if ($mass['login'] == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

То есть если в БД есть пользователь с таким логином и с таким паролем , то у нас в $mass['login'] выберется из БД логин этого пользователя

fetchAll() этот метод возвращает массив массивов поэтому, в вашем случае нужно использовать $row[0]['login'] без цикла while или же используйте просто $stmt->fetch() и вы сможете получить логин пользователя по  $row['login']

Comment: В вопросе спрашивается не как проверить логин и прароль, а зарегистрирован ли пользователь. Это две разные задачи.

Comment: вы можете скопировать код который я привел и заменить три раза "password" на "email" и будет вам проверка зарегистрирован ли человек по такому логину и почте